# how can i solve varriale not found error?

Tags: jsp, jdbc

im using following code.
an error is occoring saying " could not find symbol / variablr at line 46 which is

```
 <td><%= rs.getString(1)%></td>
```

something is wrong with variable rs

``````````````````````````````````````````````
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    

 - List item

   <head>
    <script>
         function f()
         {
            rs.next();
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%   
       try
       {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/banquet", "root", "root");
         Statement st=conn.createStatement();
         String query = "SELECT * FROM halldetails";
         st = conn.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery(query);
         rs=st.getResultSet() ;
         rs.next(); 
       } 
       catch(Exception e)
       {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
     %>  
    <form>
        <table cellspacing="20" cellpadding="25">
         <tr>
           <td>Name:<td>
           <td><%= rs.getString(1)%></td>
         </tr>
        </table> 
         <input type="button" value="NEXT" onclick="f()" />
    </form>
</body>
     
    

</html>
`````````````````````````````````````````````
``````````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 0):

At the point you are attempting to use the variable `rs`, it has gone out of scope.  It went out of scope at the closing brace after `rs.next()`, just before the `catch` block.

A better way would be to declare a variable outside the `try` block, record the value from the result-set in that, and write that out:

```java
       String name = "";
       try
       {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         // rest of code omitted for brevity
         rs.next();
         name = rs.getString(1);
       } 
       catch(Exception e)
       {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

and then later in your JSP:

```html
           <td><%= name %></td>
```

---

Looking at your code I can guess what the next problem you will have is.  You have  a JavaScript function `f()` which attempts to call `rs.next()`.  The problem is that this function only gets called when the page has been sent to the browser by the server.  At that point the result-set `rs` that your JSP uses on the server will have long been closed, and it will be the browser attempting to execute `rs.next()`, not the server.  The browser won't have the connection to the server, or the database.  It won't know what `rs` is.  You will just get an error `rs is not defined`.

If you want to be able to show the next row after the one you're currently showing, there's a lot more work to do.  I won't show how to do it here: that's a whole separate question.